# Error using simple-credentials in Spring Boot AWS Context - bean already bound

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

Given my applicationContext.xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aws-context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-5.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context/spring-cloud-aws-context.xsd">

    <aws-context:context-credentials>
        <aws-context:instance-profile-credentials/>
        <aws-context:simple-credentials access-key="${aws.accessKeyId}" secret-key="${aws.secretKey}"/>
    </aws-context:context-credentials>
    
</beans>
```

And this error:

The bean 'credentialsProvider', defined in null, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in null and overriding is disabled.

What is wrong with the xml?